# Generating defined amount of the rows based on max/min of other Dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe where I have calculated metrics below:

[Metrics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmFvi.png)

I need to generate fixed amount of the rows for new data frame (for example 1000 or 2500), where each row will have a random number no less than minimum and no more than maximum, ideally change for +/- 1%.

I was trying solution as below, but without success so far:

```
Intervals = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[df['Close'].min(), df['Close'].max()],[0.4, 0.6],[0.4, 0.6],[0.20, 1.], [0.3, 0.4], [0.2, 0.3]]))

df = pd.DataFrame(list(Intervals.apply(lambda x: np.random.uniform(low=x[0],high=x[1], size = 2500).T, axis=1)))

print(df.T)
```

Any ideas how it can be approached?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop over the columns in your metrics dataframe and create an array of random numbers using `numpy.random`:

```
pd.DataFrame({
    column: np.random.uniform(
        low=metrics[column].min(), high=metrics[column].max(), size=1000
    )
    for column in metrics.columns
})
```

Comment: Thank you! Generally works, how to ensure change between items are limited to 1%, should I add somewhere conditional statement or apply separate analysis?

Comment: @MichalMorrison Do you mean that no two elements should be apart more than 1% of the whole range? You could use a combination of `np.linspace` with a small amount of noise added e.g. using `np.random.normal`. This very much depends on your desired properties, so will need some tweaking.